"/gazebo/apply_body_wrench" service is missing
I want to apply force to an object in ROS2 Gazebo but "/gazebo/apply_body_wrench" service is not available in ros2 service list. After adding "libgazebo_ros_force.so" plugin to URDF following the syntax described here as:
<plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_force.so" name="gazebo_ros_force">
          <bodyName>link_1</bodyName>
          <topicName>/box_force</topicName>
</plugin>

I am getting the the following new services in ``ros2 service list```:
             Service                                       Type

/ball_spawner/describe_parameters           rcl_interfaces/srv/DescribeParameters
/ball_spawner/get_parameter_types           rcl_interfaces/srv/GetParameterTypes
/ball_spawner/get_parameters                rcl_interfaces/srv/GetParameters
/ball_spawner/get_type_description          type_description_interfaces/srv/GetTypeDescription
/ball_spawner/list_parameters               rcl_interfaces/srv/ListParameters
/ball_spawner/set_parameters                rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParameters
/ball_spawner/set_parameters_atomically     rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParametersAtomically


But I am unable to find "/gazebo/apply_body_wrench" service in this list.
